# what is the significance of specifying the keystore name and alias with Java keytool import?

Tags: java, x509certificate, keystore, keytool

A Tomcat server will be run on /programs/x64/java/jdk1.8.

Therefore, we would need to run keytool to import certs from services that the apps running on the Tomcat server need encrypted access.

What is the significance in the keystore name and cert alias? Do they affect how the Tomcat is able to access the stored certs?

What is a good upgrade-proof strategy, such that certs/keystore imported/created by current JDK version are visible to a new JDK version installed?

Comment: I've only used the keystore attribute in the `server.xml` file in the context of installing an SSL certificate into Tomcat.  Maybe you can tell us what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I want a general answer about the functionary use of keystore and alias

Comment: "The cert you import to Tomcat would typically be coming from ..." Not asking about that. "The keystore password is necessary ..." not asking about that.

Answer (score 1):

> Therefore, we would need to run keytool to import certs from services that the apps running on the Tomcat server need encrypted access.

Only if those applications run on servers that have self-signed certificates. NB the result of this process is called a truststore, not a keystore. A keystore is for your own private key and certificate.

> What is the significance in the keystore name

The keystore name is the name of a file.

> and cert alias?

The cert alias is the name of the certificate.

> Do they affect how the Tomcat is able to access the stored keys?

There are no stored keys. Only certificates. Tomcat doesn't care what their aliases are.

> What is a good upgrade-proof strategy, such that certs/keystore imported/created by current JDK version are visible to a new JDK version installed?

Avoid the whole problem, by insisting that the application servers use CA-signed certificates. Self-signed certificates aren't worth the paper they're printed on.

Comment: "The cert alias is the name of the certificate." I know. But why? "keystore name is the name of a file." - so ... what is the significance, since it doesn't seem to matter what I name the keystore name.

Comment: 1. Why what? Why do certificate entries have names? So you can update them, delete them. 2. There is *no* significance in the filename. It's a filename. As long as you tell Tomcat what it is, it doesn't matter.